# NameError: name 'Factory' is not define i don't know why

Tags: python

I am new to Python 2.7 and practicing to write to a csv file using the faker module which creates dummy test data.  I am writing the header first.
I am getting an error Factory is not defined.
I'm not sure why it thinks factory is not defined.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Automation/Python/Write to file practice/csv_write_test.py", line 18, in 
    fake = Factory.create()
NameError: name 'Factory' is not defined

My code snippet is:

```
from faker import factory
import csv

def create_fake_stuff(fake):
""""""
stuff = ["email", "bs", "address", "city", "state", "paragraph"]
for item in stuff:
    print "%s = %s" % (item, getattr(fake, item)())

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
write_to_csv = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
write_to_csv.writerow(['id,' 'TITLE,' 'FNAME,' 'SNAME,' 'GENDER,' 'ADD1,'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
fake = Factory.create()
create_fake_stuff(fake)
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: I think you meant `factory.Factory.create()` or `from faker import Factory` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing a [`factory` module](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/factory.py), but need to import a [`Factory` class](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/factory.py#L15). Replace:

```
from faker import factory
```

with:

```
from faker import Factory  # or from faker.factory import Factory
```

Comment: @RiazLadhani it is, `factory` and `Factory` are two very different things.